# Template variable not rendering in url_for() function in Jinja template with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, web, jinja2

**Problem:**

I am trying to use a template variable inside the `url_for()` function in the `href` attribute of a `link` tag in a Jinja template with Flask. However, the template variable is not being rendered.

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/pages/{{user}}.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <p>This is my website.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```py
from flask import render_template, url_for

@app.route("/")
def home():
    user = "admin"
    return render_template("index.html", user=user)
```

When I visit the `/` route, I get a 404 error for the CSS file, because the template variable is not being rendered.
I am trying to use a template variable inside the `url_for()` function in the `href` attribute of a `link` tag in a Jinja template with Flask. However, the template variable is not being rendered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/pages/{{user}}.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <p>This is my website.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```py
from flask import render_template, url_for

@app.route("/")
def home():
    user = "admin"
    return render_template("index.html", user=user)
```

When I visit the `/` route, I get a 404 error for the CSS file, because the template variable is not being rendered.

**Expected behavior:**

The CSS file should be loaded from the `/static/css/pages/admin.css` path.

**Actual behavior:**

A 404 error is returned for the CSS file.

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Create a Flask application.
2. Create a Jinja template with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/pages/{{user}}.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <p>This is my website.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Create a Flask route that renders the template:

```py
from flask import render_template, url_for

@app.route("/")
def home():
    user = "admin"
    return render_template("index.html", user=user)
```

4. Start the Flask application.
5. Visit the `/` route in your browser.

**Question:**

How can I fix the problem so that the template variable is rendered in the `url_for()` function in the `href` attribute of the `link` tag?

**Additional information:**

I am using Flask version 2.1.2 and Jinja version 3.1.2.

Comment: if you use chatgpt to reformulate your question, please take the time  to check chatgpt's text.